# I can't start tests via junit4/maven/intellijIdea

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit4, intellij-idea-2016

I can't start tests via `intellijIDEA`.
After installing some times it working. Today occurred error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

And other errors:

```
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
```

Comment: `Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'ruslan-All-Series', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_91'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
`

Comment: `Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`

Comment: `Process finished with exit code 255`